# How to update Mongodb fields with omitempty flag in Golang inner structure

Tags: go, mongo-go-driver

```
//...
type UserInfo struct {
    OpenId    string `json:"openId,omitempty"`
    UnionId   string `json:"unionId,omitempty"`
    NickName  string `json:"nickName"`
    AvatarUrl string `json:"avatarUrl"`
    Gender    int8   `json:"gender"`
    Province  string `json:"province"`
    City      string `json:"city"`
    Country   string `json:"country"`
}

type User struct {
    Id          primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt   string             `json:"createdAt" bson:"createdAt"`
    Openid      string             `json:"openid" bson:"openid,omitempty"`
    PhoneNumber string             `json:"phoneNumber,omitempty" bson:"phoneNumber,omitempty"`
    UserInfo    UserInfo           `json:"userInfo,omitempty" bson:"userInfo,omitempty"`
    Status      bool               `json:"status" bson:"status,omitempty"`
}
//...
res, err := collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), user)
//...
```

The `UserInfo` is also a struct. After inserted is shown in the images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lx75.png)

I don't want the `UserInfo` field when it is empty. What should I do? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm so sorry.I found the solution. `UserInfo   *UserInfo           \`json:"userInfo,omitempty" bson:"userInfo,omitempty"\`` :|

Comment: Would you please update your question with a detailed answer, so others can question as guidance in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is add `*` to the type of innerStruct that means pointer.Jus like this:

```
//...
type UserInfo struct {
    OpenId    string `json:"openId,omitempty"`
    UnionId   string `json:"unionId,omitempty"`
    NickName  string `json:"nickName"`
    AvatarUrl string `json:"avatarUrl"`
    Gender    int8   `json:"gender"`
    Province  string `json:"province"`
    City      string `json:"city"`
    Country   string `json:"country"`
}

type User struct {
    Id          primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt   string             `json:"createdAt" bson:"createdAt"`
    Openid      string             `json:"openid" bson:"openid,omitempty"`
    PhoneNumber string             `json:"phoneNumber,omitempty" bson:"phoneNumber,omitempty"`
    UserInfo    *UserInfo           `json:"userInfo,omitempty" bson:"userInfo,omitempty"`
    Status      bool               `json:"status" bson:"status,omitempty"`
}
//...
res, err := collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), user)
//...
```

Now the UserInfo will be omitted when insert into mongodb or `json.Marshal()`.Hope to give others little helps :)